# Where is the log files for hashicorp consul?

Tags: logging, service, windows-services, consul

I try to setup [hashicorp consul](https://www.consul.io/)(as a windows service) to log data to file. The doc says to set the log_level in the config file but nothing about where the logfiles will end up on a Windows computer? There is a consul monitor but I need it to log to file.

```
{
  "data_dir": "data",
  "log_level": "INFO",
  "bootstrap_expect": 1,
  "server": true,
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "ui": true,
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "addresses": {
    "http": "0.0.0.0"
  },
  "ports": {
    "http": 8518,
    "dns": -1,
    "https": -1,
    "rpc": 8218,
    "serf_lan": 8318,
    "serf_wan": 8418,
    "server": 8618
  }
}
```

In this case I need to log when the consul goes on/off line and what services that the consul knows about and of course errors/warnings.

How do I log to file with [hashicorp consul](https://www.consul.io/)?

BestRegards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, you have to run the service from the command prompt and then redirect STDOUT to a file. It's not the best solution but its the only way I've found.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible and fairly simple.**

I honestly can't remember where I found this out but it did take some hunting originally. I discovered that you can modify the **ExecStart** of the service that is created on the yum installation for consul. By adding a **-log-file=some-path** at the end of that line you can direct the logs from consul to say /var/log/consul for instance.

```
[Unit]
Description="HashiCorp Consul - A service mesh solution"
Documentation=https://www.consul.io/
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/consul.d/consul.hcl

[Service]
User=consul
Group=consul
ExecStart=/usr/bin/consul agent -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/ -log-file=/var/log/consul/
ExecReload=/bin/kill --signal HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

EDIT: I found the documentation for this setting [at Hashicorp](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options)

The relevant option is documented [very nicely here](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_log_file) other than that you'll likely need to add the setting in the service configuration.

Comment: You can also create an additional file under /etc/consul.d/ with the [log_file](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#log_file) option set to the desired file system path.

Answer (score 0):

Logs will be recorded in the system logs.

Run this to retrieve the logs for a service, in reverse order (ie. the most recent first):

`sudo journalctl -u consul.service -r`

Answer (score 0):

Consul can write logs to a file with [`-log-file`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/e5963b35dbdc0a6e20180eb78dd83936c29c2b72/website/source/docs/agent/options.html.md#_log_file) flag, for example:

```
.\consul.exe agent -config-file config.json -log-file ./logs/ -log-rotate-bytes 1048576
```

NOTE: target folder (./logs/ in the example above) must exist before starting consul.